NodeJS, collation is not kept
I have an issue with my NodeJS API.
The API is deployed on a VPS and is working well but not for long. Indeed, after some days, the accentuated characters, like "é", are not well encoded anymore. In the end, using Postman, I see my accentuated characters replaced by �
On my NodeJS, I use this to define the encoding :
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: process.env.PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB,
  charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
});

But maybe it's not the good way to do. Maybe also the issue is not on nodeJS side, but on the host of my VPS (OVH).
What do you think ?
Thank you

Please check your database charset, I mean, maybe you config in the API this charset but when the init database is a different charset @Boysteuf

To answer to @phankieuphu with an image, I think the database in phphmyadmin is well set. Is it the right place to check that ?
